# Broadcasting issues with numpy.linalg.lstsq

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, broadcast, least-squares

I am working on some image analysis algorithm and am trying to use numpy for doing a least square fitting. To illustrate what I am trying to do, I have generated a very simple test case:

```
A = np.zeros((2, 2))
A[0, 0] = 1
A[0, 1] = 3
A[1, 0] = 4
A[0, 1] = 5
```

So this is my simple A matrix in the Ax = b type equation.

Now, in this test case my image is basically a simple 2x2 image and at each of the point I have 2 measurements. So, in my case I simulate it as follows:

```
x = np.array([[13, 24], [13, 24], [13, 24], [13, 24]])
x = x.reshape((2,2,2))
```

Now, this represents my 3-dimensional image where I have 2x2 grid and two values associated with each pixel. I can solve this pixel by pixel as;

```
np.linalg.lstsq(A, x[0, 0, :]) # fit at pixel (0, 0)
```

or

```
np.linalg.lstsq(A, x[0, 1, :]) # fit at pixel (0, 1)
```

However, as soon as I try something like:

```
np.linalg.lstsq(A, x) # fit at all pixels together
```

It complains that x is 3-dimensional array and I am not sure how to tell it that it needs to broadcast over the first two dimensions.

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1733) and [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html), I'm not sure `numpy.linalg.lstsq` supports broadcasting.

In your test case, however, you can use `np.linalg.solve` which does support broadcasting

Comment: Unfortunately, solve places a bit too many restrictions on the design matrix, which make it difficult for me to use. I also had issues on broadcasting over the correct axes. So, using solve, I got the correct answer whenever I did the individual pixels but wrong one when using the last example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape `x` to have shape (2, K), with the pairs of the pixel values in the columns. Call [`lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html), and then restore the shape of the result.

For example, here are `A` and `x`:

```
In [86]: A

Out[86]: 
array([[ 1.,  5.],
       [ 4.,  0.]])

In [87]: x
Out[87]: 
array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]])
```

Reshape `x` as `y`, with pixel values in the columns:

```
In [88]: y = x.reshape(-1,2).T

In [89]: y
Out[89]: 
array([[0, 2, 4, 6],
       [1, 3, 5, 7]])
```

`y` is the shape we need for `lstsq`:

```
In [90]: result = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)

In [91]: result[0]
Out[91]: 
array([[ 0.25,  0.75,  1.25,  1.75],
       [-0.05,  0.25,  0.55,  0.85]])
```

Grab the solution, and restore the shape to match `x`:

```
In [92]: sol = result[0].T.reshape(x.shape)

In [93]: sol
Out[93]: 
array([[[ 0.25, -0.05],
        [ 0.75,  0.25]],

       [[ 1.25,  0.55],
        [ 1.75,  0.85]]])
```

Check that the solution is what we expect by solving a couple pixels individually:

```
In [94]: sol[0,0]
Out[94]: array([ 0.25, -0.05])

In [95]: np.linalg.lstsq(A, x[0,0])[0]
Out[95]: array([ 0.25, -0.05])

In [96]: sol[1,0]
Out[96]: array([ 1.25,  0.55])

In [97]: np.linalg.lstsq(A, x[1,0])[0]
Out[97]: array([ 1.25,  0.55])
```

Comment: Of course! So, it can take an MxK array. Thanks so much!

Comment: There is just a small correction. In the example, it works because the number of observations and parameters is the same but one can have more observations than the parameters, in which case the reshape should be something like: sol = result[0].T.reshape(x.shape[0:-1],(2,)). Here, number of observations is 2 as well and it is not an overdetermined system, so it is fine.